# How to encode a dataset with string examples with SVM?

Tags: python, classification, svm

i've been wondering what's the best strategy to encode examples of the form

> ["word-a", "word-b",...,"word-n"]

for a classification algorithm like SVM that takes only float numbers.

Clearly an array with the size of my dictionary where i map every position to a word is too naive to work.

I've been looking at string kernels but i'm not sure it's what i need.

So how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what i was looking for was the "One-hot" or "One-of-K" approach.

http://code-factor.blogspot.it/2012/10/one-hotone-of-k-data-encoder-for.html